# Weird huge row height when using cellspace on p-column type with empty cell

Tags: tables, cellspace

When using this code, all is OK:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|S{p{1cm}}|}
    \hline
    foo & bar \\
    \hline
     a & É \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting output is OK]

But when a `p`-column type with the `cellspace` contain an empty cell, as in this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|S{p{1cm}}|}
    \hline
    foo &  \\
    \hline
     a & É \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I obtain a white first page, and on the second page, an huge height for the first row:

[image: Resulting output is not OK]

The log contain this message:

> Overfull \vbox (482.37025pt too high) has occurred while \output is active

Is this the expected behaviour?

To workaround this, instead of an empty cell, I can use an explicit white space (`\` ). But perhaps there is a better solution?

Same bug with an `m`-column-type (from the `array` package). `l`, `c` and `r` column-types aren't affected by this strange behaviour.

Comment: You didn't specify any value for `\cellspacetoplimit `` or `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

Comment: @Bernard Default value of `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` is `1pt` (see line 66 and 67 of https://github.com/JosselinNoirel/cellspace/blob/master/cellspace.sty). The problem is not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `>{\arraybackslash}` to the last column:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|S{>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}|}
    \hline
    foo & \\
    \hline
     a & É \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the technical reason for the necessity to adding `>{\arraybackslash}` on this `S`-column, when a cell is empty? Why only for `p` or `m` column type?

Comment: I don't know the details, but as far as I know, there may be problems with the \\ row breaking in tables when the last column  is `p{some length}` or similar, because it may happen that latex doesn't know whether it is used for a new row  or for a line break in the cell?

Comment: But without the `S` specification, `>{\arraybackslash}` isn't needed. Anyway, I have opened an issue on the GitHub project for the `cellspace` package.

Comment: You did well. I guess there's an interaction between cellspace, the paragraph-like column types and \\, for some reason. I  already had a similar problem with an `X` column type.

Answer (score 2):

For information, if you use `nicematrix` and its parameter `cell-space-limits`, you don't have that problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=1pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|p{1cm}|}
    \hline
    foo &  \\
    \hline
     a & É \\
    \hline  
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.